# How to pass float to a pybind11 function expecting an int

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pybind11

I copied the example from the pybind11 documentation:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

Built it like so:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I/usr/include/python3.7 -o example.so example.cpp
```

Then:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from example import *
>>> add(1, 2)
3
>>> add(1.0, 2.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int, arg1: int) -> int

Invoked with: 1.0, 2.0
>>>
```

I realize I could rewrite `add` to take `double` arguments and then truncate them inside the body of `add`. But is there a way to tell pybind11 that it's ok to to pass floats to the function (even though it takes `int` arguments) and have it perform the conversion automatically?

According to the docs, the opposite (conversion from integer types to `double`) is done implicitly and automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Silently and implicitly truncating to `int` is a terrible thing to allow, and `pybind11` won't do it for you. If you must allow it, you can make an overloaded function for each parameter type, and have the `double` variant do the truncation on your behalf (keep in mind, this might not just lose precision after the decimal; `double` can express numbers much larger than any integer type, so bad things'll happen for such numbers).

A rough example for doing this would be:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
int add_int(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}
int add_double_as_int(double i, double j) {
    return add_int((int)i, (int)j);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("add", &add_int, "A function which adds two integers");
    m.def("add", &add_double_as_int, "A function which adds two floats after truncating to int");
}
```

At the C++ level, the functions have different names (you *might* be able to avoid this with creative casting [similar to the examples for doing it with class methods](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#overloaded-methods), but it's hardly worth the trouble), but at the Python level, they'll appear as a single API with multiple prototypes described in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

C++ is strongly typed. It will do automatic type conversion of basic types only when it can be done safely. Since an integer can't represent every value that a double can C++ can't automatically perform the conversion. So you'll need to explicitly do the conversion yourself. I'm not sure how this is done in python. In C++ it is best done with:

```
#include \<cmath\>

double dbl = 3.5;

int newval = std::round(dbl);
```